# How to know the type of args in c#

Tags: c#, generics, arguments, command-line-interface, command-line-arguments

I am trying to create a program that adds two arguments regardless of what types the arguments I am passing. Now, I am trying to know the type of the args and then create a new object of my generic class extensionMethods.cs that has the same type as my args.

The result that I am expecting:

```
if args[0] = 1
args[1] = 2
result = 3
---
if args[0] = 1
args[1] = a
result = 1a
---
if args[0] = a
args[1] = b
result = ab
```

extensionMethods.cs

```
public class extensionMethods<T> {
  public T argument1 { get; set; }
  public T argument2 { get; set; }

  public T Add() {
    dynamic dynamicArg1 = argument1;
    dynamic dynamicArg2 = argument2;
    return dynamicArg1 + dynamicArg2;
  }
}
}
```

Program.cs

```
 internal class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
      var argument1 = args[0];
      var argument2 = args[1];

      /* Always String !
          Type argType = args[0].GetType();
          Console.WriteLine(argType);
      */

      if (float.TryParse(args[0], out float argument1Int) &&
          float.TryParse(args[1], out float argument2Int)) {
        extensionMethods<float> obj = new extensionMethods<float>();
        obj.argument1 = argument1Int;
        obj.argument2 = argument2Int;
        Console.WriteLine(obj.Add());
      }

      else if {
        (int.TryParse(args[0], out int argument1Int) &&
         int.TryParse(args[1], out int argument2Int)) {
          extensionMethods<int> obj = new extensionMethods<int>();
          obj.argument1 = argument1Int;
          obj.argument2 = argument2Int;
          Console.WriteLine(obj.Add());
        }
         .
         .
         .

        else {
          extensionMethods<string> obj = new extensionMethods<string>();
          obj.argument1 = args[0];
          obj.argument2 = args[1];

          Console.WriteLine(obj.Add());
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

With this code the program works without any problem. However, I guess it is not the right way to have if statement for each data type to check. I have tried to get the type using `GetType()` However, the result is always string.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/math ?

Comment: well, `GetType` won't check for if your type is **convertable** to some other type, but - well - for the exact type. So of course it returns `string` for your args. However for checking if your strings are **convertible** to a specific type, you should parse it. So `TryParse` is perfect here.

Comment: The type _is_ string. You may be able to parse that string as a float or int, but that does not make the string variable a float or int variable.

Comment: Seems your class doesn't support any `T`, only those you can add. And three specific but different types of add. So generics might not be the best approach.